# View journalctl logs of running service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

I'm using `sudo journalctl -u some-service -f` to see the logs of a service. However, when the service is running, the last log is always of the form:

`***Plenty of logs from previous instance of Some Service***
Apr 14 09:03:05 user-computer systemd[1]: Stopped Some Service.
Apr 14 09:03:35 user-computer systemd[1]: Started Some Service.`

What I expect to see:

`***Plenty of logs from previous instance of Some Service***
Apr 14 09:03:05 user-computer systemd[1]: Stopped Some Service.
Apr 14 09:03:35 user-computer systemd[1]: Started Some Service.
***New logs from current instance of Some Service***`

Why can't I see the logs from the currently running instance of the service? Only once I stop/restart the service, can I see the logs from that instance.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was application specific and had nothing to do with systemd or journalctl.

For my Python services, I had to disable the output buffer:

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
Environment="PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x"
```

For my PHP application, I simply had to add a newline character before the content got flushed.